# Excluding files/directories when using Fortify SCA with CMake and C++?

Tags: cmake, fortify

I am invoking my Unix, CMake-based, C++ build in the following way (using *bash*)

```bash
CC="sourceanalyzer -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b test-project -exclude \\\\\\\"/usr/include\\\\\\\" -verbose gcc" CXX="sourceanalyzer -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b test-project -exclude \\\\\\\"/usr/include\\\\\\\" -verbose g++" cmake ..
make
sourceanalyzer -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b "test-project" -verbose -scan -f results.fpr
```

The crazy number of backslashes is needed to escape the double quotes correctly so that they make it to *sourceanalyzer*:

```bash
$cat CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/sca/bin/sourceanalyzer")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1 " -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b test-project -exclude \"/usr/include\" -verbose g++")
```

I also tried without the backslashes with the same effect, but I don't think it's supposed to work - everything I can find about this states the excludes have to be in quotes, especially if * is included - and eventually I will want that/

```bash
CC="sourceanalyzer -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b test-project -exclude /usr/include -verbose gcc" CXX="sourceanalyzer -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b test-project -exclude /usr/include -verbose g++" cmake ..
```

When I run `sourceanalyzer -fcontainer -Xmx1G -b "test-project" -verbose -scan -f results.fpr` after building the project, it still picks up lots of issues in */usr/include*

I dug through the [Fortify documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2110/SCA_Guide_21.1.0.pdf) and for *-exclude* it says: *When you integrate the translation with a compiler or a build tool, Fortify Static Code Analyzer translates all source files that the compiler or build tool processes even if they are specified with this option*. That seems a little ambiguous to me probably because I don't know much about the process - am I really 'integrating' with the compiler?

So, the questions are 1. is it possible to use the *-exclude* options with CMake and C++; 2. If so, is there a neater way than using 7 backslashes before each double quote?

Comment: "_is there a neater way than using 7 backslashes before each double quote?_" Depends on what shell you're using. In Bash, unless you use single-quote strings, you have to use two backslashes to make a literal backslash. i.e. you can use just one if you want to get a literal backslash and you use single-quote strings instead of double-quote strings.

Comment: "_am I really 'integrating' with the compiler?_" what do you mean by that? What is your end goal? maybe I just don't understand because I know nothing about SCA.

Comment: Using bash (added to question). That's the thing, I'm not really sure what the documentation means by "integrating", I'm very new to Fortify.